# Can I update a burned disk content from 12.04 to a newer version like 13.04?

Tags: livedvd

I have burned a disk image of Ubuntu 12.04 and I would like to know if I could update the content.
Maybe it's a stupid question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible unless it's a CD-RW or DVD-RW.

Comment: Nope, it's just a DVD-R.